# How to query for a phrase on SQL database of words?

Tags: mysql, sql

**I am using `MySQL`** and I have an SQL database of of songs with a table that consists of 8 columns of information on words of a song. each row represents a single word from the songs lyrics:

1. `songSerial` - the serial number of the song
2. `songName` - the song name
3. `word` - a single word from the song's lyrics
4. `row_number` - the number of the row that the word is found
5. `word_position_in_row` - the number of the word in the row alone
6. `house_number` - the number of the house the word belongs to
7. `house_row` - the number of the row in the house that the word is found in
8. `word_number` - the number of the word out of all the songs lyrics

example for a row: { 4 , The Scientist , secrets , 8 , 4 , 2 , 1 , 37 }

**Now I want to query** all the songs that contains a group of words. For instance all the words that have the sentence: "I Love You" in them. **It must be in that order** and not from different rows or houses.

Here are scripts in my oneDrive for creating the databastable and about 400 rows:
[TwoTextScriptFilesAndTheirZip](https://1drv.ms/f/s!An3amVaASD6_jTbURdkSZXWFDsLa)

Can anyone help ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use `join`s:

```
select s.*
from songwords sw1 join
     songwords sw2
     on sw2.songSerial = sw1.songSerial and
        sw2.word_number = sw1.word_number + 1 join
     songwords sw3
     on sw3.songSerial = sw2.songSerial and
        sw3.word_number = sw2.word_number + 1 
where sw1.word = 'I' and sw2.word = 'love' and sw3.word = 'you';
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
where concat_ws(' ', sw1.word, sw2.word, sw3.word) = 'I love you'
```

This is worse from an optimization perspective (indexes using `word` do not help performance), but it is clear what the query is doing.

Searches of this type suggest using a [full text index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html).  The only caveat is that you will need to remove the stop word list and index all words, regardless of length.  ("I" and "you" are typical examples of stop words.)

Comment: We might want to use `word_position_in_row` in place of `word_number`, and also include `house_number` and `row_number` in the matching criteria (according the spec "not from different rows or houses"). And those joins cry out to have suitable indexes available.

Comment: Thanks you query worked. I know it's like brute force but it's enough for me(I hope haha). I also added the row_number critirea so thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

This is an expensive approach for a large table, assuming `word` is not null,  we could do something like this:

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 16777216 ;

SELECT t.song_serial
     , t.house_number
     , t.row_number
  FROM mytable t
 GROUP
    BY t.songserial
     , t.house_number
     , t.row_number
HAVING CONCAT(' ',GROUP_CONCAT(t.word ORDER BY t.word_position_by_row),' ') 
  LIKE CONCAT('% ','I love you',' %')
```

We would definitely want a suitable index available, e.g.

```
... ON `mytable` (`songserial`,`house_number`,`row_number`,`word`)
```

---

If one of the words in the phrase is infrequent, we might be able to optimize a bit with a search for that infrequent word first, and then get all of the words on the same row ...

```
SELECT t.song_serial
     , t.house_number
     , t.row_number
  FROM ( SELECT r.songserial
              , r.house_number
              , r.row_number
           FROM mytable r
          WHERE r.word = 'love'
          GROUP
             BY r.word
              , r.songserial
              , r.house_number
              , r.row_number
       ) s
  JOIN mytable t 
    ON t.songserial   = s.songserial 
   AND t.house_number = s.house_number
   AND t.row_number   = s.row_number
 GROUP
    BY t.songserial
     , t.house_number
     , t.row_number
HAVING CONCAT(' ',GROUP_CONCAT(t.word ORDER BY t.word_position_by_row),' ') 
  LIKE CONCAT('% ','I love you',' %')
```

That inline view `s` would benefit from a covering index with word as the leading column

```
... ON `mytable` (`word`,`songserial`,`house_number`,`row_number`)
```

Answer (score 0):

You look for these words and relative search positions: 1 = I, 2 = love, 3 = you. Let's compare them with two song lines:

```
            And I love, love, love you
real pos:   1   2 3     4     5    6
search pos: -   1 2     2     2    3
diff:       -   1 1     2     3    3

            I miss you and I love you
real pos:   1 2    3   4   5 6    7
search pos: 1 -    3   -   1 2    3
diff:       0 -    0   -   4 4    4
```

If we look at the position deltas of the first line, we get 1 (twice), 2 (once), and 3 (twice).

For the second line we get deltas 0 (twice), and 4 (thrice).

So for the second song line we find a delta with as many matches as search words, for the first line not. The second line is a match.

And here is the query. I assume we have a temporary table `search` filled with the search words and relative positions for readability.

```
select distinct w.songserial, w.songname, w.house_number
from words w
join search s on s.word = w.word
group by
  w.songserial, w.songname, w.row_number, w.house_number, w.house_row, -- song line
  w.word_position_in_row - s.pos -- delta
having count(*) = (select count(*) from search);
```

This query is based on:

- a song is identified by `songserial` + `songname` + `house_number`
- a song line is identified by `songserial` + `songname` + `row_number` + `house_number` + `house_row`

This may be wrong; I don't know what house and house number mean in reference to a song. But that'll be easy to adjust.